# access first row of group_by dataset

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe`df1 with columns a,b,c. I want to assign c=0 to the first row of the `dataset` returned by `group_by(a,b)`. I tried something like

```
t <- df1 %>% group_by(a,b) %>% filter(row_number(a)==1) %>% mutate(c= 0)
```

But it reduced number of rows. Expected output is

```
a     b     c
a1    b1    0
a1    b1    NA
a2    b2    0
a2    b2    NA
```

Comment: what's in `df1` and what's expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seq_along` to number elements in each group from `1` to the total number of elements within each group (`2`, in this case). Then use `ifelse` to set the first element of 'c' for each group to be `0` and leave the other element as is.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(a, b) %>% 
  mutate(c = ifelse(seq_along(c) == 1, 0, c))
#  A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Groups:   a, b [2]
#  a     b         c
#  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#1 a1    b1       0.
#2 a1    b1      NA 
#3 a2    b2       0.
#4 a2    b2      NA
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(c("a1", "a2"), each = 2),
                 b = rep(c("b1", "b2"), each = 2), 
                 c = NA)
df
#   a  b  c
#1 a1 b1 NA
#2 a1 b1 NA
#3 a2 b2 NA
#4 a2 b2 NA
```